# How to get the PID of a java command started by a script? I only receive the PID of the script

Tags: bash, process

I would like to store the pid of a *Java* command, to be able to stop it later.

That java runs a server, so it won't finish by itself, making a `$!` reading not possible.
But reading `$$` returns me the pid of the bash script, not the one of the *Java* command...

My `start.sh` script is this one:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo $$

java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED \
   -jar target/application-metier-et-gestion.jar
```

it displays: `204630` then starts the server.

But a `ps aux`shows me:

```
lebihan   204630  0.0  0.0   6820  3184 pts/1    S+   07:31   0:00 /bin/bash ./start.sh
lebihan   204631 90.8  1.6 29503752 1099948 pts/1 Sl+ 07:31   0:46 java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens j
```

How can I get the `204631` too, to be able to store it, and later kill my java server?

Comment: It sounds like you're reinventing service management which your OS already has?

Comment: @user1686 it seems, yes! But it's because each process I have to start cannot be ran through a single `ExecStart` statement, because it calls few scripts to start an executable. And I do not know of to create (if it is possible and if it's a good idea) a multi-line service that would be able, for each application represented, to keep in mind two or three pid. But I have to think about what you're writing twice, really.

Comment: Do you mean the real script runs three separate Java processes? That should just be three separate `.service` units then, each with one ExecStart, and with appropriate dependencies between them (Wants/Requires + Before/After).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line that invokes `java` so that is starts with `exec java ...` instead of just `java ...`:

```
echo PID is $$
exec java ...
```

This will replace the running shell with the java process, using the same PID that you've already captured.

Alternatively, as suggested by [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas), run the `java ...` command in the background with `&` and `bash`'s `$!` variable will contain the PID of the java process:

```
java ... &
javaPID=$!
echo PID is $javaPID
```

(From `man bash`: *`!` Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background*)

Comment: alternatively, run the java command in the background with `&` and bash's `$!` "special parameter" will contain the PID of the java process. From `man bash`: *`!` 
  Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin (see JOB CONTROL below).*

Comment: @cas that's as valid an answer as mine

Comment: yep, it is. it's so close to yours that it doesn't really need a separate answer, just a comment is enough. feel free to incorporate the alternative into your answer if you like. or not. as you please.